# C# razor in Webmatrix and JQgrid

Tags: c#, razor, jqgrid, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I'd like to know if there is a way to use JQgrid in Webmatrix with C# and Razor instead of using the built in WebGrid helper.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can use any jQuery plugin within a WebMatrix (ASP.NET Web Pages) site. You can [generate JSON for it using the JSON Helper](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/160/WebMatrix-Working-With-The-JSON-Helper), and then follow some of the demos at the jqGrid site.